# SQL Trying to limit a column with a certain value to two entries

Tags: sql, command, row, limit

I am trying to create a SQL command that allows for just two entries (at a given time) to have a certain column variable. ie... If two people are already in room #2, do not allow anyone else into that room, but if one person is in the room... then allow them.

So the column that can only have two of the same number would be "RoomNumber" in this instance.

Comment: I think you need to use an update and/or Insert trigger.

Comment: What database are you using?  What are the tables you are using?

Comment: This kind of logic is probably best enforced in your application, not the database (e.g. what happens if you want to change the rule, or allow for an exception).

Comment: Well StuartLC is absolutely correct. But even if you need to implement this logic at Database level then Check count value of specific "RoomNumber" if its 1 then allow or else deny.

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution That would be "if its 1 ***or 0***" of course ;-)

Comment: I have the data populating a Gridview (application side). I was having trouble pulling data from the Gridview to create a check count value.

Comment: Thanks @TrimantraSoftwareSolution... I created a query to count the amount of customers in that room and am feeding that data to the application and will limit addition access from that side. Thanks everyone!!